# Slick carousel being used recognized as a class when using Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, slick.js

I have a project that I recently changed to typescript. In this project, I use slick as my carousel component. The component I use it in uses a very simple logic: if the window is mobile (width state hook), render the carousel. If not, render another component. Here's the code:

```
import Slider from "react-slick";

...

const ParentElement = (width > 992) ? ItemsWrapper : Slider;
    return (
            <ParentElement {...settings}>
                //some code
            </ParentElement>
    );
```

After the implementation of typescript into the project, now I get this error on `ParentElement`:

[image]

If I understand it correctly, it is recognizing Slick as a class, not as a component. Does anyone know why is this happening? Why did vanilla React recognize Slick as a component and now typescript as a class? I looked all over for this behavior but found nothing online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that JSX is syntactic sugar for React's component function calls, so assigning ParentElement the way you've done won't work. You need to make it a function that returns JSX, or better yet just move the conditional down into the return value of your component:

```
/* ...the rest of your component... */
return width > 992 ? (
    <ItemsWrapper {...settings}>{/* some code */}</ItemsWrapper>
  ) : (
    <Slider {...settings} />
  );
```

Comment: Just tried it out. Even using the correct JSX syntax it still doesn't know that Slider is a component. And even so, it is odd the the code I posted on my question worked without Typescript and its not anymore.

Comment: So it's giving you the same error, or a different one? Have you tried yarn add --dev @types/react-slick ?

Comment: The same error. @types/react-slick is present.

Comment: Will you update your question with the complete new code for the component?

Comment: I was re-testing your solution and reading the error again I found that it did work. The reason it was not working with your code was some invalid properties I was passing down with settings! Much appreciated, man!